# Identify which module a function was exported from in Julia

Tags: namespaces, julia

I'm looking for a way to identify which module a function was exported from in Julia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `<function name>.env.module` to retrieve the name of the module which it comes from.

Ex.

```
julia> sum.env.module
Base
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<function name>.env.module` approach in the accepted answer no longer works in Julia 1.x. Instead, you can use the 
[`@which`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.@which) macro:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> @which sum
Base

julia> @which enumerate
Base.Iterators

julia> @which deleterows!
DataFrames
```